# NotImplementedError when trying to get image.size in Django with Azure Storage

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In forms.py in Django, I have a particular snippet of code where I'm cleaning an image before uploading. The relevant snippet is:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(label='Upload Photo')
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user','previous_retort')   
        fields=('avatar',)


    def clean_avatar(self):
        image=self.cleaned_data.get("avatar")
        if image:
            try:
                if image.size > 1000000:
                    #raise ValidationError("File too big")
                    return 0
            except:
                pass
            image = Image.open(image)
            image = MakeThumbnail(image)
            return image
        else:
            raise 0#ValidationError("File is corrupt")
```

In views.py, I have:

```
class UserProfileEditView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = "edit_profile.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)[0]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("profile", kwargs={'slug': self.request.user})
```

`image.size` crashes for me, giving the error:

```
Exception Type:     NotImplementedError 
Exception Location:     /home/hassan/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py in size, line 114
```

Line 114 in storage.py merely points to the vicinity of:

```
def size(self, name):

    """

    Returns the total size, in bytes, of the file specified by name.

    """

    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Also `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage` in **settings.py**.

And the `UserProfile` model in models.py is:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    previous_retort = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_avatar_to_location, storage=OverwriteStorage(), null=True, blank=True )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s's profile" % self.user
```

Anyone encountered this sort of a thing before? Please ask me for more information in case you feel it's missing.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the value of `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` in settings.py?

Comment: *storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage*

Comment: AzureStorage does not implement `image.size`. This is probably because you only have indirect read/write access to the azure server, so getting a file size is much more expensive than on your local file system.

Comment: Any workaround you can suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried to reproduce your issue, however it seems working fine on my side. Here is my code snippt:

`forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from PIL import Image, ImageFile

class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
    image_file=forms.ImageField(
        label='upload an image'
    )
    def clean_avatar(self):
        image=self.cleaned_data.get("image_file")

        if image:
            print image.size
            if image.size > 1000000:
                raise ValidationError("File is too big")
            image = Image.open(image)
            #image = MakeThumbnail(image)
            return image
        else:
            raise ValidationError("File is corrupted")
```

`view.py`:

```
def image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.clean_avatar()
            return HttpResponse('some pages')
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'app/image.html',
        {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

As your requirement is to clean the image before put to Azure Storage, so I think it should be relative to django storage handers, Maybe there are some misunderstandings on my side, will you please provide more code snippets to help us to reproduce your issue.

### update

On my side, I have to do something like a trick to reproduce your issue:

```
def clean_avatar(self):
    #this image here, is the object <InMemoryUploadedFile, len() = 23170>
    image=self.cleaned_data.get("avatar")
    #use PIL.image to open it, can parse into <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1003x366 at 0x2AA9E50>
    #i assume you leverage your custom OverwriteStorage() function and dierctly returned the PIL image object 
    image = Image.open(image)
```

I debugged in VS, i explored the image object, found that there is a `fp` object which contains the `_szie`:
[image]

So you can try to use `image.fp._size` instead of `image.size`

Comment: Hey Gary, I added some more code to the original question as per your advise. Hopefully this will help you isolate the issue?

Comment: could you provide your `UserProfile`? As on my side, it is difficult to guess your object. As it works fine on my side without `UserProfile`.

Comment: Added that too Gary.

Comment: I think I have reproduced the issue in something like a trick, anyway, you can refer to the update in my answer. If any further concern,  feel free to let me know.

Comment: So this error is coming when images are being "re-submitted". If I submit a new image, e.g. sandra-3.png, `image.size` works fine. But if I resubmit the form containing that image, then I get an error (and the image by then has become `avatars/9fc3a7ff-f95f-47e6-aa20-720be748beb0.jpg`) where `avatars` is a folder within my Azure blob.